# COM object and javascripts

Tags: javascript, com

I tried to consume 3rd. party COM object from JavaScript. from some reason, it crashes my internet explorer with no apparent reason when the object is beig disposed.

The COM object works perfectly when using it from other environments (like vb and C#)

any suggestions? can it be IE security setting that cause the problem? does anynone knows any keypoints for COM object usage from JavaScryp/Iexplorer?

Many thanks,

john

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you getting any HRESULT value?

Answer (score 1):

As a first check, try the same script in different browsers. If the problem only shows up in IE, you might want to make sure the COM object supports [IObjectSafety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768224(VS.85).aspx).